# libgdx can't show texture immediately,showed after block 4S

Tags: java, libgdx

I encount a problem:
libgdx can't show texture immediately,
the texture can be showed after block 4S.
here is my code in render

```
SpriteBatch sprite=stage.getSpriteBatch();
        sprite.begin();
        for(Player p : teamHeros){
            p.draw(stage.getSpriteBatch(), Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        }
        sprite.end();
```

I can add player by press D, but the newly added player can't be showed.
if i use Thread.sleep(4000), it can show;
if i add a debug point,and block here ,it can show;
Can anybody tell me why?
sorry about my poor english.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "texture can be showed after block 4S".

Comment: How/where are you loading the texture for `Player`?  (Are you using `AssetManager` somewhere?)

Comment: I mean the texture will be showed,If I add "Thread.sleep(4000);" before  "p.draw(stage.getSpriteBatch(), Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());" .

Comment: I find the reason : I didn't set the width and height of the texture. Still Thanks for your reply!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you have to code on a new thread because pixmap class takes time for byte conversion and sometimes returns a temporary pixmap in case the process hasnt finished so its better to run on a seperate thread and your problem will be solved.